# The separable degree of an algebraic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $k \subset E \subset F$ be a tower of algebraic extensions. If the separable degree $[F:k]_s$ is finite, then $[F:k]_s = [F:E]_s[E:k]_s$.

Here $[F:k]_s$ is defined to be the number of embeddings $F \to \bar k$ fixing $k$.

One essential component of the proof is: If $H: E \to \bar k$ is an embedding of fields fixing $k$, and $G: F \to \bar k$ is an embedding of fields fixing $E$, then they can be assembled to to be a field extension $F \to \bar k$ fixing $k$. How to make sense of this?

Naively I can define an embedding $F \to \bar k$ by sending elements in $E$ according to $H$, and the rest of the elements according to $G$. But this is not necessarily an embedding because $G$ and $H$ might take two elements, one in $E$ and one not in $E$, to the same element in $\bar k$.

Comment: Note that ring-homomorphisms between fields are always injective.

Comment: I suppose [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816719/if-l-f-and-f-e-are-separable-then-l-e-is-separable?rq=1) could be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, it should be fixing $E$.@DietrichBurde

Comment: @penny, what do you mean by fixing $E$ here? You would need some embedding of $E$ into $\bar{k}$ a priori in order to fix $E$. Is this embedding the same as $H$? If so, then there is no problem. Otherwise, what is this embedding?

Comment: I am using the fact that $\bar E = \bar k$. @jgon

Comment: @penny, be careful with using equalities with algebraic closures. Algebraic closures are not unique, merely isomorphic. There are many different isomorphisms between $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{k}$ that result in different embeddings of $E$ into $\bar{k}$. In fact for each $k$-embedding of $E$ into $\bar{k}$, there is at least one isomorphism $\bar{E}\cong \bar{k}$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Doesn't fix one of such identification work in the proof of the degree formula?